# How do I make a text element take up half the height of the parent container in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code:

```
containers.add(Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2-20,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2-20,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    value2,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      inherit: false,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    )
                  ),
                ]
              )
            ));
          });
        }
      });
```

The container itself goes into a list which is passed into a GridView eventually becoming a 2-wide grid down the screen. I want to make it so that the text height is half of the height of the container defined by the width and height `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2-20`. Is this possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Expanded` together with `FittedBox`:

```
class HalfHeightText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  
  const HalfHeightText({required this.label});
  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 20,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 20,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          // ===========================================
          Expanded(
            child: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              child: Text(
                label,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  inherit: false,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const Expanded(child: SizedBox.shrink()),
          // ===========================================
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Result:

```
HalfHeightText(label: "Text")
```

[image: Text's example]

Answer (score 0):

use
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.50,
its mean like user of width 50% or else MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.25, mean 25%